# Wrong keyboard cursor position on HTML page with uses "scale"

Tags: javascript, css, html, contenteditable

When you create a new `contenteditable` `<span>` on a page where `scale` is used, the keyboard cursor is sometimes put at a wrong position with Firefox.

[image]

Example : click on the right side of the window in the following snippet example : the "Strawberry" text will appear, but the `I` keyboard cursor will be in a wrong position.

**How to have a good `I` keyboard cursor position for `contenteditable` objects ?**

---

```js
    window.onload = function() {
      var container = document.createElement("div"),
        wrapper = document.createElement("div");
      container.style.position = "absolute";
      wrapper.style.position = "relative";
      container.appendChild(wrapper);
      document.body.appendChild(container);
      container.style.transform = "scale(0.6)";    
      zoom = 0.6;  

      window.onclick = function(e) {
        if (e.target.className == 'texte') { return; } 
        var tb = document.createElement('span');
        tb.className = "texte";
        tb.contentEditable = true;
        tb.style.fontSize = '40px';
        tb.style.position  = 'absolute';
        tb.textContent = 'strawberry';
        tb.style.top = e.clientY / zoom + 'px';
        tb.style.left = e.clientX / zoom + 'px';
        wrapper.appendChild(tb);
        tb.focus();
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Text map</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Running your code snippet the cursor for me seems to appear fine in the right position.....

Comment: this is not an answer, maybe a comment, but not an answer. Did you try with Firefox ? By the way you need to open the snippet "Full page" and click on the right of the page to see it happen.